# How to connect a 220v gfci that has no neutral coming from the load

Tags: electrical

On a boat dock with a220v boat lift I have pulled 2 hots and a ground as that’s all that is required to operate the lift motor. My Bldg dept is requiring a GFCI 220 breaker. I assume the pigtail will go to the neutral bar in the panel but what do I do to connect to the GFCI?

Comment: I take it this GFCI is going at the panel?

Answer (score 5):

Connect the hots to the GFCI. Since there is no neutral on the circuit, there cannot be any current on the non-existent neutral non-wire, and any imbalance will be between the hot legs. Not connecting the neutral wire to the GFCI is *only* a problem if there IS a neutral wire to not connect...